# Set via Data-Binding API a well known attribute value

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-attributes, android-binding-adapter

I have an custom attribute from a custom view defined line this:

```
<declare-styleable name="ExampleView">
    <attr name="order">
        <enum name="byValue" value="0" />
        <enum name="byKey" value="1" />
    </attr>
    <!-- and some more attributes -->
</declare-styleable>
```

Android Studio detects this and offers me a autocompletion, which is great. So the xml attribute will look like `app:order="byValue"`. However since I want to use a `BindingAdapter` from the data binding API, I need to use it with an `@` sign like this: `app:order="@{byValue}"`, unfortunately this does not compile.

Then I tried to use a constant which I use internally too like this: `app:order="@{com.example.views.ExampleView.ORDER_BY_VALUE}"`, but this does not compile too. I can just use `app:order="@{0}"`, sure this works because it is defined like that, however it is not intuitive why I am using `0` there.

Any idea how can I write a more readable code to solve this issue?

Comment: I think I got the same issue so to add some information, the error log I get is basically this : "android data binding cannot find setter". And only if I want to use something with an @{}. Hope you will find a solution.

Comment: I have to try it later again. Maybe the import tag is the trick. I read something about it.

Comment: @rekire were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Wow after 4 years a comment to this old question. Sorry I cannot even remember this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to create code for the enum values:

```
object Order {
    const val BY_VALUE = 0
    const val BY_KEY = 1
}
```

Import the class / object holding these enums to your XML:

```
<import type="com.example.Order" />
```

Then you can reference them:

```
app:order="@{Order.INSTANCE.BY_KEY}"
```

Comment: Well, I don't know if that is correct, but for an answer which is waiting so long you get the accepted state for that.